# google map marker unity

Tags: c#, google-maps, unity-game-engine, marker

I can add a static google map through API in Unity but I can't drag it nor add a marker in it. I just wanna know to add marker on a static map when you are using it through API.

The given script used is below :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class googleAPI : MonoBehaviour
{

    public RawImage img;

    string url;

    public float lat;
    public float lon;

    LocationInfo li;

    public int zoom = 14;
    public int mapWidth = 640;
    public int mapHeight = 640;

    public enum mapType { roadmap, satellite, hybrid, terrain }
    public mapType mapSelected;
    public int scale;


    IEnumerator Map()
    {
        url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=" + lat + "," + lon +
            "&zoom=" + zoom + "&size=" + mapWidth + "x" + mapHeight + "&scale=" + scale
            + "&maptype=" + mapSelected +
            "&markers=color:blue%7Clabel:S%7C40.702147,-74.015794&markers=color:green%7Clabel:G%7C40.711614,-74.012318&markers=color:red%7Clabel:C%7C40.718217,-73.998284&key=AIzaSyCEELUzZC6wuQ6QRao4fHOLBpKQ-fPpkWI";
        WWW www = new WWW(url);
        yield return www;
        img.texture = www.texture;
        img.SetNativeSize();

        StartCoroutine(Map());

    }
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        img = gameObject.GetComponent<RawImage>();
        StartCoroutine(Map());
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Static Maps is a static image, I wouldn't expect any dynamic behavior there.

Answer (score 0):

Please note at this line

> markers=color:blue%7Clabel:S%7C40.702147,-74.015794&markers=color:green%7Clabel:G%7C40.711614,-74.012318&markers=color:red%7Clabel:C%7C40.718217,-73.998284

You should add lat and long for that
example:

> markers=color:blue%7Clabel:S%7C "+your lat+ " , " + your long + ".